# ¿Porque no me deja utilizar un registro 2 veces en este caso ID_CATEGORY en otra pagina con el mismo formato html y php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

**Tengo una tabla con productos y sus respectivos géneros pero no me deja volver a utilizar el ID_CATEGORY de Accion que es el género abajo del nombre del producto y dentro de los productos, en este caso videojuegos, por este error.**

Ya busqué a detalle en el código pero practicamente copié y pegué, y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error solamente para el genero del videojuego.

- Llevo rato revisando el codigo y no veo cual puede ser el problema. Puede que sea en la forma en que acomodé la tabla o tenga que hacer otra nueva.
- En este caso incluí mejor el código completo de la pestaña porque de plano la copié y pegué, pero solo seleccioné el género de **Accion** de los productos, para asignarlos por categorías como un filtro.
- Tambien intente agregando otra columna como **ID_CATEGORY2** pero tampoco funcionó.

[image: Pagina mostrando todos los caracteres de la tabla - Pestaña 1]

[image: Error en cuestion - Pestaña 2]

[image: tabla products]

```
<?php 
    include "config.php";  
    session_start();
      
    include "cart.class.php";
    $cart=new Cart();
  
    $data=[];
    $sql="select * from products";
    $res=$con->query($sql);

    if($res->num_rows>0)
    {
        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
    }
?>
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="Inicio_carro.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krub:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="Inicio_carro_ac.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <script src="js_inicio/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js_inicio/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include "navbar.php"; ?>
        <div class='container mt-5 pb-5'>

        <main>
        <div id="contenedorSlider" class="contenedor-slider">
            <!--Inicio del Carrusel-->
            <div id="slider" class="slider">
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/The last.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/GTA.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/Fort.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/GODOW.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/Zelda.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/SSB.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/MKart.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/ASC.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/MB.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
                <div class="slider__section"><img src="../img/SMO.jpg" class="slider__img"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="btnPrev" class="btn-prev">&#60;</div>
            <div id="btnNext" class="btn-next">&#62;</div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br><a name="ac"></a>

        <p>.</p>
        <h2 style="margin-left:195px; "><strong> Accion</strong></h2><br>


            <div id="imagenes_filtro"><br>
                <h3><strong>GENEROS</strong></h3>
                <ul style="margin-left: 30px;">
                    <li><a href="Inicio_carro.php#tod">Todos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Inicio_carro_ac.php">Accion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Inicio_carro_av.php">Aventura</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Inicio_carro_te.php">Terror</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Inicio_carro_di.php">Disparos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Inicio_carro_de.php">Deporte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Inicio_carro_vr.php">Vr</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

                <main class="contenedor_3 sombra">
                <div class='row'>

                <!-- Datos mostrados y acomodados -->

                <?php 
                    $data=[];
                    $sql="SELECT IMAGE,PRODUCT,PRICE,PID FROM products WHERE ID_CATEGORY IN ('Accion');";
                    $res=$con->query($sql);
                
                    if($res->num_rows>0)
                    {
                        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            $data[]=$row;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ?>
                
                <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
                    <div class='col-md-3 mt-2 mw-25 mh-50'>
                        <div class="card">

                        <a href="view_details.php?id=<?php echo $row["PID"]; ?>" 
                           class=''><img style ="height: 210px; width: 202px;" class="card-img-top" src="images/<?php echo $row["IMAGE"]; ?>" ></a>
                          <div class="card-body">

            <h5 style="font-size:18px;" class="card-title"><strong><?php echo $row["PRODUCT"]; ?></strong></h5> 

                            <!-- Error --><h5 style="font-size:18px;" class="card-title"><strong><?php echo $row["ID_CATEGORY"]; ?></strong></h5>
                            <p style="font-size:18px;" class="card-text"><!-- Error --><strong>$ <?php echo $row["PRICE"];?></strong></p>
                            <a href="view_details.php?id=<?php echo $row["PID"]; ?>" 
                               style="width: 173px; margin-left: 0px; font-size: 13px;" class='btn btn-primary' >Ver Detalles</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                
                <!-- Datos mostrados y acomodados -->

                </main>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        
        <script src="../js/slider.js"></script>
        <script src="../estreno2/js_estreno/search3.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Así implementé la tabla**

```
 <br>
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ` products ` ( <br>
  `PID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, <br>
  `PRODUCT` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', <br>
  `PRICE` double(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00', <br>
  `IMAGE` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', <br>
  `DESCRIPTION` text, <br>
  `ID_CATEGORY` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', <br>
PRIMARY KEY (`PID`) <br>

)  <br>
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6; <br>
```

Comment: puedes añadir el codigo del schema de tus tablas? no vaya  a ser que tengas hecha alguna relacion uno a uno en lugar de uno a varios, y sea una restriccion de sql...

Comment: Listo, ese seria el scheme no?

Comment: ¿puedes explicar mejor tu problema?  No acabo de entender lo que te sucede. ¿que quieres conseguir, donde y que error te da? ¿cuando dices **insertar** a que te refieres? no veo ninguna consulta INSERT

Comment: En si no me deja mostrar el genero dentro de ID_CATEGORY abajo del nombre del juego, porque ya lo estoy usando en otra parte de la pagina. Seria en el filtro que ya utilizo Accion que esta con todos los generos pero al querer que solo me muestre Accion no me deja volver a insertar dicho genero.

Comment: Vale, perdona, no habia visto bien el error en la imagen. Ahora lo veo. Supongo que debes cambiar esto: `$sql="SELECT IMAGE,PRODUCT,PRICE,PID FROM products WHERE ID_CATEGORY IN ('Accion');";`  por esto: `$sql="SELECT ID_CATEGORY, IMAGE,PRODUCT,PRICE,PID FROM products WHERE ID_CATEGORY IN ('Accion');";` y se arreglará (espero)

Comment: Si era eso ya puedes borrar la pregunta, es un descuido en la consulta, pues al no poner en el SELECT la columna `ID_CATEGORY` entonces el `$row['ID_CATEGORY']` no existe y da ese error de índice en el array $row.

Comment: Si funciono carnal, gracias en verdad. Me la pase como 2 o 3 horas buscando o cambiando el codigo pensando que habia escrito algo mal jaja

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad si me funciono

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)  Lo que decia, borra la pregunta, es un fallo de comprensión del error (ahora ya lo sabes) y un descuido leve en la consulta. Y de este tipo de errores ya tenemos resueltos en este sitio a decenas, no creo que haga falta dejar uno más, ni creo que por el título de la pregunta ayude a nadie más ni nadie se acerque a mirarla como no sea para intentar responderla. Gracias